# PWM DC Motors with different gear ratios

Tags: pwm, dc-motor, duty-cycle

I have two dc motors, 9V, but each have different gear ratios. I would like to synchronize their rpm using pwm. Is there a way of calculating the duty cycle I need to make the one with a smaller gear ratio slower?

Comment: The way is called "division" and "multiplication".

Comment: You won't synchronize dc motors without some feedback mechanism that tells you speed from each. PWM or a linear DC voltage is no difference - you need feedback elements to do this. Maybe you mean something different - maybe you mean "approximately get both motors running at the same speed"?

Comment: The ratio of gear ratios is the ratio of duty cycles .

Comment: To reinforce Andy's point, if you load both motors equally, the one with lower gearing will slow down more as the motor must supply more torque. So if you match speeds at one load and change the load they will lose synch.

Comment: @autistic, no, the ratio of gear ratios is *not* the ratio of duty cycles, at least for any reliable implementation.  This requires closed loop control, either in the sense of manual adjustment to calibrate, or much preferably real-time closure of the loop via a feedback sensor.

Comment: Off course it does .the duty gear ratio stuff just gets you in the ball park so a closed loop scheme is easier to get stable.

Comment: Do you want to get the rpm's roughly the same, or do you want to synchronise their rotation angles? The first can be done with open loop PWM, depending on your definition of 'roughly'. The second requires closed loop control.